# remote debugging in pycharm, debugging a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pycharm, jython, remote-debugging

Good Day!
I have a script which runs on **Python3.5**, It spawns a **subprocess** which runs a java application.

```
subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/java","-jar",<pathToMyJar>])
```

This Java application internally invokes some of my python scripts which runs on **Jython2.5**.
So I want to debug those **Jython** scripts, I'm enabling remote debugging in the start of my jython script. Check the following code which does that,

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(libspath, "pycharm-debug.egg"))  
import pydevd  
pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=9999, stdoutToserver=True, stderrToServer=True, suspend=True)
```

I have created a debug server on my Pycharm with same host and port as above, every time before running my script I start my server on Pycharm but I can't able to debug my Jython scripts.On pycharm I can able to see **waiting for process connection..**, after that nothing happens.
what is wrong with my approach, is there anything I'm missing here.
I'm using Pycharm-2018.1.2 professional version on ubuntu.